# Need help building package on Ubuntu

Tags: packaging

I'm trying to build a local package on Ubuntu 12.04.01 LTS using [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging). I'm having problems getting debuild to pass the correct `make` command, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The project's makefile:

```
install:
    /bin/mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/lib/site_perl/
    /usr/bin/install -m 0755 src/MyMod.pm $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/lib/site_perl
```

That's it - I'm only wanting to drop in a single `.pm` file for the time being, to make sure I'm getting things right.

The `debian/rules` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_install:
    $(MAKE) DESTDIR=$$(pwd)/debian/mylibs install
```

Output of `debuild` (snipped to the important part):

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/scratch/jberninger/debbuild/mylibs-1.0'
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/site_perl/
```

So it appears to me that debbuild isn't passing DESTDIR to `make`...

Help?

Update:
`debuild -us -uc` works (as in gives me a functional `.deb` package) when I modify the Makefile to:

```
install:
    /bin/mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)opt/lib/
    /usr/bin/install -m 0755 src/MyMod.pm $(DESTDIR)opt/lib/
```

Why? Is Ubuntu/Debian allergic to underscores? To more than three directory levels? I've changed *nothing* else.

Comment: Why can't you use `debian/install` if all you need to do is copy a file to some place?

Comment: Because this is an artificially simplified case, I need the interaction with "make install" to work properly.

Comment: do you, though? Can't you just observe where the files end up and write an `install` file accordingly?

Comment: Yes, actually, I do. For this case, I could work around it using `debian/install`, but if `debuild` is supposed to operate with `make install` properly, then I want it to operate with `make install` properly.